# Puppet reporting without master

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, hiera, puppet-dashboard, puppetdb

I am planning a Puppet infrastructure for about 100-200 servers. This is the design so far:

1. Stash (git) for storing puppet config (not planning on using a master).
2. Hiera to query either yaml, json, or possibly couchdb for sensitive (passwords) variables.
3. PuppetDB?

Point 3 is my problem. I need reporting and it seems like PuppetDB will collect everything I need. However, as I understand, it will only collect and present the data in a REST api. My question is, what then would I (can I) use to grab that data and present it in a clean, view-able way? Do I need PuppetDB for this or can I have my nodes send their reports to a different report processor?

Update 1: 
Not sure if this matters, but we are about 70/30 Linux/Windows.

Comment: I didn't realize you could use puppetdb without a puppetmaster, but it looks like you can. http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppetdb/1.6/connect_puppet_apply.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Puppet is rather flexible about reports. There are a number of [processors](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#reports) to choose from, and you will most likely end up with a bunch of `pson` (JSON) files.

This allows you to implement your own consumer for reports, though open source solutions will obviously lift a lot of work from you.